# Understanding JavaScript querySelectorAll looping

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I understand there are simpler ways to do this but I read that this was the best practice:

```
var forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        callback.call(scope, i, array[i]); 
    }
};


var myNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('i');
forEach(myNodeList, function (index, value) {
    console.log(index, value); 
});
```

Some things I can't quite grasp:

- What is the purpose of the scope parameter in the function and callback?
- I thought the purpose of callbacks were to make use of 'this'?
- What is so special about this method as opposed to a simple for loop?

Comment: `scope` is setting the context or `this` of your callback. `.call` docs will have more info on that. The use of callbacks has no direct relation to context or `this`. `this` is an object available to all functions. Callbacks are primarily used for async work (however promises have arrived and rendered them redundant for that purpose, technically you still provide a `.then` a callback). Its not really all that special vs a standard `for` loop. It does provide syntax similar to the native `array.forEach` which is good.